# load NULL data into different table with the help of SQL*Loader

Tags: oracle, null, sql-loader

I have a CSV which contains 8 column. It has NULL data for few of the rows.

To load CSV data, I have created 2 tables with the same definition.

1) `TABLE_NOT_NULL` to load Not NULL data

2) `TABLE_NULL` to load NULL Data

I am successfully able to load data into `TABLE_NOT_NULL` with below `when` condition:

```
insert into table '<TABLE_NAME>' when '<COLUMN_NAME>'!=' '.
```

Now, I want to load NULL data into the table called `TABLE_NULL` but I am not able to filter out only NULL value with when condition.

I tried too many things but none of them worked; like:

a)  `insert into table '<TABLE_NAME>' WHEN '<COLUMN_NAME>'=BLANKS`

b)  `insert into table '<TABLE_NAME>' WHEN '<COLUMN_NAME>'=' '`

Can anyone please suggest any workaround or solution for it?

Comment: Table definitions, sample data and your whole control file might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround?

## 1

- Load everything into TABLE_NULL
- insert into TABLE_NOT_NULL select * From TABLE_NULL where column is not null
- delete from TABLE_NULL where column is not null

## 2

- load everything into TABLE_NOT_NULL
- rows, that contain NULL values, won't be loaded but end up in the BAD
  file
- using another control file, load BAD file into TABLE_NULL

## 3 (EDIT)

- instead of SQL*Loader, create an external table - it acts as if it was an *ordinary* Oracle table, but is (really) just a *pointer* to the file
- you'd then write 2 INSERT statements:

`insert into table_not_null 
 select * From external_table where column is not null;`

```
insert into table_null
select * From external_table where column is null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround but I have around 2 Milion records. So I feel better to reduce the number of DML statements. Want to perform both task with Single CTL file.

Comment: Heh, I think I saw you saying *workaround*, didn't I?

Comment: @Rahul, have a look at the 3rd workaround - an external table. I'd say that it might really work

Comment: ,I cant use it because of limitation.

Comment: Which limitation, if I may ask?